# Is to possible to forbid access to tables in own schema - Oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-design, permissions, vpd

Lets assume that we have the following situation:
We have an Oracle schema/user: USER_TEST (with the "create session" privilege). 
SYS as SYSDBA creates couple Tables on schema USER_TEST. Is it possible to forbid access for the user USER_TEST to tables on his schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the schema is the user in oracle. In other databases, where the schema and user are actually different things (and appropriately so), then you could have a schema name that matches the user name but where the user does not have rights to the objects under that schema.

Answer (score 5):

While there is no privilege you can revoke, and I'd wonder why you can't just create another user, the answer to your question is....

#### Yes

If you have the Enterprise Edition of Oracle you can use the *Virtual Private Database* feature to prevent tables from being selected.  Here is an overview from the [Oracle Database Security Guide 11g Release 2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/vpd.htm#DBSEG007):

> Oracle Virtual Private Database (VPD) enables you to create security
>   policies to control database access at the row and column level.
>   Essentially, Oracle Virtual Private Database adds a dynamic WHERE
>   clause to a SQL statement that is issued against the table, view, or
>   synonym to which an Oracle Virtual Private Database security policy
>   was applied.
>
> Oracle Virtual Private Database enforces security, to a fine level of
>   granularity, directly on database tables, views, or synonyms. Because
>   you attach security policies directly to these database objects, and
>   the policies are automatically applied whenever a user accesses data,
>   there is no way to bypass security.
>
> When a user directly or indirectly accesses a table, view, or synonym
>   that is protected with an Oracle Virtual Private Database policy,
>   Oracle Database dynamically modifies the SQL statement of the user.
>   This modification creates a WHERE condition (called a predicate)
>   returned by a function implementing the security policy. Oracle
>   Database modifies the statement dynamically, transparently to the
>   user, using any condition that can be expressed in or returned by a
>   function. You can apply Oracle Virtual Private Database policies to
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, INDEX, and DELETE statements.

To prevent `SELECT` on a table you would need to do the following:

1. Create a function that accepts a schema/object name and returns a WHERE clause style Varchar2.  In this case it should return something like '1=2' when the user is the user you don't want to access its own objects.
2. Call the Add_Policy function of the DBMS_RLS package for each table the user owns.  This will create a policy attaching the function to the table it will protect.

Comment: I'll agree you're correct, but it's encouraging bad practice.

Comment: @Phil I certainly don't mean to encourage it and I thought I indicated that with my comment and my first sentence in my answer.  So that there is no doubt -- I do not encourage the use of VPD to limit access to a users own data.  I strongly encourage such access be limited by the creation of a separate user.  In general table owner users should always be separate from application login users.